# Possibility of packages autoupdate

Tags: updates, apps

Is there a way to set or enable auto update for apps and system packages? While I'm personally fine with clicking on update notification each time when update is available, problem is that my mom will never click on anything outside a web browser and I dont want to maintain continuously one more PC in my household :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo). Couple of options how do automatic package updates.